# Jquery fadein and out

Tags: jquery, timing, fadein, fadeout

Check this out: http://novarose.co.cc/web2/

Fade effects are kinda messed up and I do not how to make then work properly.

I want code to run in following sequence:

1. Fade out block
2. Insert new content
3. Fade in block

**My jQuery code for that page:**

$('#navigation a').click(function(){
    $.get("page.php", { page: $(this).attr('id') }, function(data){
        $('#content').fadeOut('slow').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is here: `$('#content').fadeOut('slow').html(data).fadeIn('slow'); });`
This starts the `fadeIn` before the `fadeOut` is done. You want to do this:

```
$('#content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $(this).html(data).fadeIn('slow')
});
```

The second argument to `fadeOut` is a function to be called **after `fadeOut` is finished**.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the fade out to before the ajax call:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function(){ $('#content').fadeOut('slow'); $.get("page.php", { page: $(this).attr('id') },
    function(data){ $('#content').html(data).fadeIn('slow'); }); });
```